# Can I test a link with an antivirus before accessing it?

Tags: 18.04, antivirus, clamav, url, clamtk

My problem is that I have to test a lot of links in order to check if it's safe to access the url and then check if the content is still working and I don't know how to do it with clamav.

My question is

Can I test a link with an antivirus before accessing it?

Answer (score 0):

I have found this page [virus total](https://www.virustotal.com/#/home/upload) that allows you to paste an url and then it runs almost 70 signatures to analyze it searching for virus.

Comment: If someone knows a better option I will be pleased to accept the answer. Thanks